# Difference between 'Ubuntu netboot + Xubuntu Minimal (from taskel) and 'Xubuntu'

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the following two installations:

- Ubuntu Netboot with "Xubuntu Minimal" from tasksel
- Xubuntu

I'm aware that Netboot with 'Xubuntu Minimal' is trimmed down. But I can't find out how much has been taken out (packages difference).

I've installed both in virtual machines and there's a difference of about 350~ packages. I've noticed that the minimal Xubuntu doesn't even have a browser, for example (which is fine by me). However, I'm worried that I may be missing some important (?) configurations and packages for laptop that I don't notice.

I've tried looking in the Ubuntu packages and a few other sites, but couldn't find much detailed info.

Thanks!

Comment: You're right, I gave it the wrong name. I've edited the post. I meant selecting 'Xubuntu Minimal' from the tasksel. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under the hood of Tasksel (in `/usr/share/tasksel/descs/ubuntu-tasks.desc`), you will discover the real metapackage names:

- Tasksel's "Xubuntu Minimal" simply installs the `xubuntu-core` metapackage.
- Tasksel's "Xubuntu Desktop" simply installs the `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

If you query apt about those two metapackages, you will discover that `xubuntu-core` is a dependency of `xubuntu-desktop`.

So really, the question is about which dependencies of `-desktop` are not already included in `-core`. Here's one easy way to do it:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines <(apt depends xubuntu-core) <(apt depends xubuntu-desktop)
```

This script-voodoo simply reads the dependencies of `-core` and `-desktop`, then passes those to the `diff` program, and tells `diff` that we care about non-duplicates only.

Comment: No need for temp files, just use pipes with `diff --suppress-common-lines <(apt depends xubuntu-core) <(apt depends xubuntu-desktop)`.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you! Exactly what I was looking for (: